# Inno Setup GetStringFileInfo cannot read AssemblyTitle

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup

```
AppName={#GetStringFileInfo(RootDirectory + "Sample.exe", "Title")}
```

Above Inno Setup script throws error (*"AppName has invalid value"*), although `AssemblyInfo` has below line.

```csharp
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("App Title")]
```

Based on the file; https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Files/ISPPBuiltins.iss#L152 we can see that `Title` is missing but `CompanyName`, `ProductName`, `FileVersion`, etc are given. And, I've checked `ProductName` worked well.

Is this the reason why `Title` could not be read properly?
Some old examples have `GetStringFileInfo(path, "Title")` but why did Inno Setup remove it?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answers that are helpful to you (when you are able to). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetStringFileInfo` loads information from [`StringFileInfo` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringfileinfo-block) of a binary. Note that the function is not aware of .NET at all. There's no `"Title"` field in the `StringFileInfo` block (nor ever was).

The [`AssemblyTitleAttribute` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute) actually  says:

> The property name is **File description**.

So, load `"FileDescription"` (or use `FILE_DESCRIPTION` macro from `ISPPBuiltins.iss`).